# "Illegal instruction" when run precompiled program on other machine

Tags: glibc, dynamic-linking, rpath

I have to build my program on CentOS 7 and deploy on other Linux machine. The program required newer version `glibc`, and some library which was not (and will not be) installed on target machine. So I decided to ship the executable with dynamic library. I used `patchelf` to patch `interpreter` and `rpath`.

I tested the executable on my machine and it work (also checked with `ldd` to make sure new rpath is used). But when I copy to other machine with libs, the program is failed to run. Only this line was printed:

> Illegal instruction

Here is backtrace from gdb
[image]

**Update:**
Binary
[image]
So the SIGILL was caused by `shlx` instruction in `__tls_init()` function. I don't know which library provide this function, I'm not sure it is from glibc.

I removed my glibc, which coppied from another computer and use glibc already installed on target computer, but the problem was not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> I used patchelf to patch interpreter and rpath

Your question is very unclear: you changed the interpreter and the rpath to *what*?

I *think* what you did is:

1. Build a new GLIBC version in non-standard path
2. Used `patchelf` to change your binary to point to the non-standard path
3. Copied the binary and the non-standard GLIBC to the target machine
4. Observed `SIGILL`.

Most likely cause: the non-standard GLIBC you built is not configured for your target processor, which is different from the processor used on the build machine.

By default, GCC will use `-march=native`, which means that if you build on e.g. Haswell machine, then the binary will use `AVX2` instructions, which are not supported by the target machine.

To fix this, you will need to add `-march=generic` or `-march=$target_architecture` to `CFLAGS` (and `CXXFLAGS`), and rebuild both GLIBC and the main program.

On the other hand, your GDB backtrace shows *standard* paths to GLIBC: `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` and `/lib64/libc.so.6`, so maybe I didn't understand the steps you made *at all*.

**Update:**

> I didn't build a new glibc but copy it from my machine to the target machine. My machine using E5-2690v4 but the target machine using E5-2470.

The E5-2690v4 is a [Broadwell](https://ark.intel.com/products/91770/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2690-v4-35M-Cache-2_60-GHz). The E5-2470 is an [Ivy Bridge](https://ark.intel.com/products/75266/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2470-v2-25M-Cache-2_40-GHz).

The former supports [AVX2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions), but the latter doesn't. Copying GLIBC built with AVX2 to an Ivy Bridge is likely to fail with exactly the symptoms you described (and in fact should render the Ivy Bridge completely non-working; I am surprised 
*anything* works on it at all).

Using GDB `x/i $pc` command, you can see which instruction generates `SIGILL`. If it's an AVX2 instruction, that's likely the answer.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.

I didn't build a new glibc but copy it from my machine to the target machine. My machine using E5-2690v4 but the target machine using E5-2470. I just think any program compiled for x86_64 architecture can run on any machine that using x86_64 processor

Comment: @PhạmVănThông If you merely copied GLIBC from one machine to another, what did you need `patchelf` for?

Comment: I used `patchelf` to set `rpath` and use glibc and others libraries.
 I have updated new info in the question.